# BMI Calculation always shows obese in English units

Tags: python, python-3.x

BMI calculator, when I entered the English units, it showing me obese, whatever the answer is, kind of confusing, how do I fix this bug.

```
print ("Body Mass Index Calculator")
Unit = input("Metric or English?: (enter M or E)")
if Unit == "M":
    Weight = float(input("Please enter your weight(kg):"))
    Height = float(input("Please enter your height(m):"))
    BMI = (Weight/ Height**2)
    print ("BMI:",Weight /Height**2)
else:
    Unit == "English"
    weight = float(input("Please enter your weight(lb):"))
    height = float(input("Please enter your weight(in):"))
    BMI = (weight /height *height *703)
    print ("BMI:",weight /height**2 *703)

if BMI<=18.5:
    print ("Underweight")
elif BMI>=18.5 and BMI<=24.9:
    print ("Normal weight")
elif BMI>=25.0 and BMI<=29.9:
    print ("Overweight")
else:`enter code here`
    print ("Obese")
```

Comment: Here's your problem: `BMI = (weight /height *height *703)` This line effectively evaluates to `BMI = weight * 703` and that's likely to be obese. Make it a `BMI = (weight /height**2*703)` as you have in the Meter block and things should work out fine

Answer (score 0):

Your BMI variable is wrong but you for some reason have it correct directly below it change BMI to:

```
BMI = (weight /height**2 *703)
```

Output:

```
Metric or English?: (enter M or E)E
Please enter your weight(lb):150
Please enter your weight(in):72
BMI: 20.341435185185187
Normal weight
```

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for the bmi is wrong

Replace

```
BMI = (weight /height *height *703)
```

With

```
BMI = (weight*703) /height**2
```